# Excel time format 2019-01-20T08:00:00-02:00 (or ccyy-mm-yyThh:mm:ss-timezone)

Tags: excel, iso8601

I am required to use ISO8601 date time format on Excel. Example 2019-01-20T08:00:00-02:00 (or ccyy-mm-yyThh:mm:ss-timezone). Let us say that I use this in cell A1. In cell B1, I would like to add 1 day and 8 hours, is there a formula I can use for this ? (ie: I want the date and time in cell B1 to be 2019-01-21T16:00:00-02:00

I am required to use ISO8601 date time format on Excel. Example 2019-01-20T08:00:00-02:00 (or ccyy-mm-yyThh:mm:ss-timezone). Let us say that I use this in cell A1. In cell B1, I would like to add 1 day and 8 hours, is there a formula I can use for this ? (ie: I want the date and time in cell B1 to be 2019-01-21T16:00:00-02:00

Comment: Your date in A1 will be a text string. Use text functions (this will be dependent on your Excel version) to break it apart so you can convert it to a "real time". Then add the amount of time you want to add, and convert it back to a ISO formatted string.  I suggest you do this one step at a time in helper columns so you can more easily debug your steps.  Please show your work, so we may better help you.

Comment: Thank you @RonRosenfeld, this is exactly what I have done. Your input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution for you is to put this function in module and call from any cell
like "=GetFullUTC(D12)" or like "=GetFullUTC()"

```
    Public Function GetFullUTC(Optional d As Variant) As String
    
    Dim dt As Object
    Dim tStr As String
    Set dt = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
    If IsDate(d) Then
       dt.SetVarDate d
     Else
     dt.SetVarDate Now
    End If
    tStr = dt.Value
    GetFullUTC = Left(tStr, 4) & "-" & Mid(tStr, 5, 2) & "-" & Mid(tStr, 7, 2) & "T" & Mid(tStr, 9, 2) & ":" & Mid(tStr, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(tStr, 13, 2) & Mid(tStr, 15, 4) & Mid(tStr, 22, 1) & Format(Abs(Mid(tStr, 23, 3) / 60), "00") & ":00"
    End Function
```

**keep in mind that the function return a string not a date.**